# How to add rocker/verse configuration ROOT=TRUE to docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running a docker container via docker-compose. [Here](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio) is the image I am using.

On that page link above, there's a section 'Give the user root permissions (add to sudoers)' with an example:

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -e ROOT=TRUE -e PASSWORD=yourpasswordhere rocker/rstudio
```

My question is, how can I use this ROOT=TRUE configuration within docker compose?

Tried:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  server:
    image: 123456.blah.dogs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ds/rstudio-image/main:latest
    ports:
      - 8787:8787
    environment:
      PASSWORD: test
    root: 'TRUE'
```

When I try to run this I get:

> docker-compose up
> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because:
> Unsupported config option for services.server: 'root'

How can I add the configuration ROOT=TRUE via docker-compose when running this image as a container?

Comment: `ROOT` is an environment variable and should be added under `environment` like you did with `PASSWORD`.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Many thanks